# Descobrir o número de requisições _search feitos a um index do elasticsearch

Tags: java, elasticsearch

Estou trabalhando com elasticsearch e gostaria de descobrir uma forma precisa para saber quantas requisições foram feitas a um índice do meu elasticsearch.

utilizando o comando GET - /"seuindex"/_stats, tenho algumas informações porém acredito que a de quantos SEARCHS foram feitos não está lá, não consegui localizá-la

Answer (score 1):

Você pode utilizar o endpoint `_count` para saber quantos hits ocorreram no índice, inclusive utilizando critérios:

```
GET /<index>/_count
```

Dessa forma você pode realizar a requisição da seguinte forma:

```
curl -X GET "localhost:9200/traffic/_count?q=plate:xpto1234"
```

Isso me retornará a quantidade de hits do meu critério `plate:xpto1234` em meu index `traffic`

Na [documentação](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-count.html) existem outros exemplos, bem como opções mais avançadas.